# SQL for Unique one column with order by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have data following format and want a unique one column `Cat_Code` with order by `Eff_Date`.
Can anyone help me to how to write the query? Thanks in advance.
** One more scenario added.**
    **Table Data Revised**:

```
**Emp_ID        Eff_Date    Cat_Code    Date_Updated    User_ID**
100088      27/12/2015      30      28/12/2015      FER
100088      27/12/2015      30      07/01/2016      AZI
100088      28/12/2015              28/12/2015      FER
100088      01/11/2016      30      13/11/2016      FER
100088      01/02/2019      30      23/02/2019      AZI
100088      01/08/2019      21      25/08/2019      IK
100088      16/04/2016      30      17/04/2016      FER

100054      01/01/2019      30      17/01/2019      MMAC
100054      01/08/2019      21      25/08/2019      IK
100054      05/09/2014              07/09/2014      EAL
100054      05/09/2014      30      07/09/2014      FER
100054      05/09/2014              07/09/2014      FER
100054      14/09/2014              14/09/2014      MSA
100054      25/10/2014              25/10/2014      MSA
100054      01/12/2014      30      21/12/2014      WAL
100054      28/04/2015      30      28/04/2015      IK
100054      01/05/2015      30      17/05/2015      WAL
100054      01/05/2016      30      15/05/2016      AZI
100054      13/07/2018      30      11/08/2018      AZI
100054      01/11/2018      30      12/12/2018      AJA

100086      10/03/2018      48      26/03/2018      FER
100086      01/06/2018      48      07/08/2018      AZI
100086      01/11/2016      30      15/11/2016      FER
100086      01/11/2017      48      16/07/2019      GPA
100086      01/04/2019      48      27/04/2019      AZI
100086      01/07/2019      30      13/07/2019      GPA
100086      01/07/2019      30      16/07/2019      GPA
100086      01/09/2015              15/09/2015      FER
100086      01/09/2015      30      15/09/2015      FER
100086      01/09/2015      30      16/09/2015      AJA
100086      01/09/2015      30      30/09/2015      MRA
100086      16/09/2015      30      16/09/2015      AJA
100086      01/11/2015      30      19/11/2015      AZI
100086      28/08/2016      30      28/08/2016      FER
100086      01/10/2017      30      30/09/2017      FER
100086      01/11/2017      30      12/11/2017      AJA
100086      01/11/2017      48      22/01/2018      FER



**Expected result:**

**Emp_ID        Eff_Date    Cat_Code    Date_Updated    User_ID**
100088      27/12/2015      30      28/12/2015      FER
100088      01/08/2019      21      25/08/2019      IK

100054      05/09/2014      30      07/09/2014      FER
100054      01/08/2019      21      25/08/2019      IK

100086      01/09/2015      30      15/09/2015      FER
100086      01/11/2017      48      22/01/2018      FER
100086      01/07/2019      30      16/07/2019      GPA
```

Comment: Datatype of Eff_Date column? Also which RDMS are you using as the SQL tag on this website is meant to indicate ANSI/ISO Standard SQL (SQL language specs) and not a RDMS..

Comment: Why does FER get priority over AZI? Both have the same Eff_Date.

Comment: in the table, there is the last column "Date_Updated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.[Cat_Code] is not null 
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where [Emp_ID] = t.[Emp_ID] and [Cat_Code] = t.[Cat_Code] and [Date_Updated] < t.[Date_Updated]
)
order by t.[Emp_ID], t.[Date_Updated]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6a64f77edf6ccfe9dad9b7735d7fae4a).
Results:

```
Emp_ID | Eff_Date   | Cat_Code | Date_Updated | User_ID
100054 | 05/09/2014 | 30       | 07/09/2014   | FER    
100054 | 01/08/2019 | 21       | 25/08/2019   | IK     
100088 | 27/12/2015 | 30       | 28/12/2015   | FER    
100088 | 01/08/2019 | 21       | 25/08/2019   | IK
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.
In table, "Cat_Code" is string value and I applied this query but the result comes with blank "cat_code" row.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because the code has this condition: `where t.[Cat_Code] is not null ....` so it is impossible to return `null` in `Cat_Code`.

Comment: If there is a case that these blank values in the column Cat_Code are not nulls but empty strings change the condition to: `where coalesce(t.[Cat_Code], '') <> ''...`

Comment: Could please assist me to modify your query because One more scenario added and "Cat_Code" blank has one space. Thanks

Comment: If instead of null Cat_Code can be blank with one more spaces then change `where t.[Cat_Code] is not null` to `where coalesce(ltrim(t.[Cat_Code]), '') <> ''`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added one scenario (data) and your query not given the required output. Could you please modify the query with all your tip. Thanks

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. By modifying the requirement you invalidate all the answers you have received. If you have a new requirement post a new question.

Comment: I posted, Could you please answer. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757063/sql-query-for-unique-column-with-order-by-effective-date

Answer (score 2):

A typical method that works well with the right indexes is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.eff_date = (select max(t2.eff_date)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.emp_id = t.emp_id and
                          t2.cat_code = t.cat_code
                   );
```

The index that you want is on `(emp_id, cat_code, eff_date)`.

If your dates are stored as a string, fix them!

```
update t
    set eff_date = convert(date, eff_date, 103);

alter table t alter column eff_date date;
```

You can use conversion for the logic, but the right approach is to fix the data.

Comment: Assuming `eff_date` is a date/datetime datatype then it would/should work like expected..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the result comes like this
Emp_ID Eff_Date Cat_Code  User ID
100088 27/12/2015 30  AZI
100088 01/08/2019 21  IK
100088 28/12/2015    FER

Comment: Could please assist me to modify your query because One more scenario added and "Cat_Code" blank has one space. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    EMP_ID,
    MIN(EFF_DATE) AS EFF_DATE,
    CAT_CODE,
    MAX("User ID") AS "User ID"
FROM
    DATETABLE
WHERE CAT_CODE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EMP_ID,
    CAT_CODE;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the result comes like this
Emp_ID Eff_Date   Cat_Code User ID
100088 28/12/2015    FER
100088 27/12/2015 30  AZI
100088 01/08/2019 21  IK

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server it could be:

```
select Emp_ID, Eff_Date, Cat_Code, [User ID ]
from (
    select *,
           row_number() over (partition by Cat_Code order by Eff_Date) rn 
    from DateTable
) a where rn = 1
```